# NullPointerException when drawing graph with the data retrieve from database

Tags: java, list, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, synchronization

the BrokenLineCusVisit class and BrokenLineCUsVisitView class are used to draw the line graph,Dashboardfragment is the place that i want generate graph. Well when i run the code, the following error occur:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference.
on this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mdata.size(); i++)
```

which means that "mdata" is null, but i tried run the retrieving data part seperately, it was working fine. So is it because i didnt handle sync problem correctly?(plz ignore the chinese comment in my code)

```
public class BrokenLineCusVisit {
    private String date;
    private int data;

    public BrokenLineCusVisit(String date, int data) {
        this.date = date;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}


public class BrokenLineCusVisitView extends View {
    private int width;
    private int heigh;
    public enum LockObj{
        INSTANCE;
    }

    //网格的宽度与高度
    private int gridspace_width;
    private int gridspace_heigh;
    //底部空白的高度
    private int brokenline_bottom;


    //灰色背景的画笔
    private Paint mPaint_bg;
    //灰色网格的画笔
    private Paint mPaint_gridline;
    //文本数据的画笔
    private Paint mPaint_text;

    //折线圆点的蓝色背景
    private Paint mPaint_point_bg;
    //折线圆点的白色表面
    private Paint mPaint_point_sur;
    //阴影路径的画笔
    private Paint mPaint_path;
    //折线的画笔
    private Paint mPaint_brokenline;
    //路径
    private Path mpath=new Path();
    //客户拜访的折线（BrokenLineCusVisit）数据
    private List<BrokenLineCusVisit> mdata;

    public BrokenLineCusVisitView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public BrokenLineCusVisitView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inite(context);
    }

    private void inite(Context context) {

        mPaint_bg=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_bg.setColor(Color.argb(0xff,0xef,0xef,0xef));

        mPaint_gridline=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_gridline.setColor(Color.argb(0xff,0xce,0xCB,0xce));

        mPaint_brokenline=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_brokenline.setColor(Color.argb(0xff,0x91,0xC8,0xD6));
        mPaint_brokenline.setTextSize(18);
        mPaint_brokenline.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        mPaint_point_bg=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_point_bg.setColor(Color.argb(0xff, 0x91, 0xC8, 0xD6));
        //注意path的画笔的透明度已经改变了
        mPaint_path=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_path.setColor(Color.argb(0x33,0x91,0xC8,0xD6));


        mPaint_point_sur=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_point_sur.setColor(Color.WHITE);


        mPaint_text=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint_text.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint_text.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        invalidate();
    }
    //data的set/get方法，用于设置数据
    public List<BrokenLineCusVisit> getMdata() {
        return mdata;
    }

    public void setMdata(List<BrokenLineCusVisit> mdata) {
        this.mdata = mdata;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        synchronized (LockObj.INSTANCE) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);
            //绘制白色背景
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            //绘制灰色矩形区域
            canvas.drawRect(10, 0, width, heigh - brokenline_bottom, mPaint_bg);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                canvas.drawLine(10, gridspace_heigh * (j + 1), width, gridspace_heigh * (j + 1), mPaint_gridline);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < mdata.size(); i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    mpath.moveTo(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100);
                }
                canvas.drawLine(gridspace_width * i + 10, 0, gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom, mPaint_gridline);

                if (i != mdata.size() - 1) {
                    canvas.drawLine(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100, gridspace_width * (i + 1) + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i + 1).getData() / 100, mPaint_brokenline);
                    mpath.quadTo(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100, gridspace_width * (i + 1) + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i + 1).getData() / 100);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100, 10, mPaint_point_bg);
                canvas.drawCircle(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100, 5, mPaint_point_sur);
                String data = mdata.get(i).getData() + "";
                canvas.drawText(data, gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100 - mPaint_brokenline.measureText(data), mPaint_brokenline);
                String date = mdata.get(i).getDate();
                canvas.drawText(date, gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom / 2, mPaint_text);
                if (i == mdata.size() - 1) {
                    mpath.quadTo(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom - (heigh - brokenline_bottom) * mdata.get(i).getData() / 100, gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom);
                    mpath.quadTo(gridspace_width * i + 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom, 10, heigh - brokenline_bottom);
                    mpath.close();
                }
            }
            canvas.drawPath(mpath, mPaint_path);
        }
    }

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
private FragmentDashboardBinding binding;

private Spinner spinner;
private List<BrokenLineCusVisit> mdata=new ArrayList<>();
private BrokenLineCusVisitView brokenline;
private float data;
private String UserID;



public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    synchronized (BrokenLineCusVisitView.LockObj.INSTANCE) {
        dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();


        final TextView textView = binding.textDashboard;
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        spinner = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        brokenline = (BrokenLineCusVisitView) root.findViewById(R.id.brokenline);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UserID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://comfy-aa480-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");
        DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Users");
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (s.equals("Oct")) {
                    for (int i = 15; i < 16; i++) {
                        int finalI = 15;
                        reference.child(UserID).child("10").child(String.valueOf(i)).child("AM").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    task.getException();
                                    BrokenLineCusVisit brokenline = new BrokenLineCusVisit(finalI + "", 0);
                                    mdata.add(brokenline);


                                } else {
                                    int num = Integer.parseInt(task.getResult().getValue().toString());
                                    BrokenLineCusVisit brokenline = new BrokenLineCusVisit(finalI + "", num);
                                    mdata.add(brokenline);
                                }
                                brokenline.setMdata(mdata);
                            }
                        });


                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //                for ( int i=1;i <31 ; i++){
                //                    int finalI = i;
                //                    reference.child(UserID).child("10").child(String.valueOf(i)).child("AM").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                //                        @Override
                //                        public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                //                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                //                                task.getException();
                //                                BrokenLineCusVisit brokenline=new BrokenLineCusVisit(finalI +"",0);
                //                                mdata.add(brokenline);
                //
                //
                //                            }
                //                            else{
                //                                int num= (int) task.getResult().getValue();
                //                                BrokenLineCusVisit brokenline=new BrokenLineCusVisit(finalI+"",num);
                //                                mdata.add(brokenline);
                //                            }
                //                        }
                //                    });
                //
                //
                //                }
                //                System.out.println(mdata);

            }
        });

        //
        //        for (int i = 0; i <30 ; i++) {
        //            BrokenLineCusVisit brokenline=new BrokenLineCusVisit(i+"",1);
        //            mdata.add(brokenline);
        //        }
        //        brokenline.setMdata(mdata);
        //        System.out.println(mdata);
        //        System.out.println(brokenline);

        return root;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Your compiler should give you the line in which the error occured. 
Add a comment to your code example pointing to the line that caused the error.  Then copy that line and put it seperatly below your code example. Also run in debug mode to find out where the code stops working and add this information to the op. Also use multiline commenting to comment out big pieces of code. // is only for one line use  /* and */ for multiline. oh, and please start using English comments.

Comment: Addendum: I tried to compile your code, but is just seams impossible. Are there other custom classes or imports associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth a shot: Does replacing

```
this.mdata = mdata;
```

with

```
this.mdata = new List<>(mdata);
```

do anything?

I am not very good with lists, so it is just a guess. But if that line causes the error, I guess the list is not initialized.
mdata seams also to be used in a getter method above it. Try to declare it in the class scope and move the line `List<BrokenLineCusVisit>` to the top of the class. Also repace the return statement of getMdata with `return this.mdata`. Not related to the question but it will cause problems, I think.